# How do I use Perl keys() from a function return value?

Tags: perl, hash

I know about the Perl `keys()` function and would like to use it on a hash I have, but don't see any reason to set a variable to it. Let me explain in code two ways:

Normal:

```
my %hash = ReturnsHash();
foreach (keys(%hash)) {
    ...code...
}
```

The way I'd like:

```
foreach (keys(ReturnsHash())) {
    ...code...
}
```

With the second way I get this error message(`Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash or array (not subroutine entry)`) Is the second way possible? If so how?

Comment: It's possible pretty much exactly the way you wrote it.  Have you even tried this approach?  If so please explain how it failed.

Comment: I added the error, I am also using 5.012 and warnings

Comment: @cdhowie: that is a 5.14+ experimental feature

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Contrary to its name, `ReturnsHash` doesn't return a hash. It's impossible for a sub to return a hash. Subs can only return a list of scalars. If you do

```
sub ReturnsHash {
   my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2 );
   return %hash;
}
```

you're doing

```
return 'a', 1, 'b', 2;
```

Since you can't do

```
keys('a', 1, 'b', 2)
```

you can't do

```
keys(ReturnsHash())
```

Now, what you could do instead is return a reference to a hash

```
sub ReturnsHashRef {
   my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2 );
   return \%hash;
}
```

aka

```
sub ReturnsHashRef {
   return { a => 1, b => 2 };
}
```

in which case you can do

```
keys(%{ ReturnsHashRef() })
```

Comment: I just stumbled on `keys(%{ ReturnsHashRef() })` before I read your post, thanks for the explanation and correct answer!

Comment: Other way is to create a hash reference from the list returned and dereference it as input to the `keys` function, like `%{ {ReturnsHash()} }`.

Comment: @Birei, Yeah, but that's something you want to avoid if at all possible. I can't think of when `return %hash;` would ever make sense. (Well, maybe if the function is intended to be called in scalar context.)

Comment: Even setting aside whether or not returning a hash would ever make sense, Perl is certainly doing more work if you flatten a hash to a list, return the list, and then copy it into an anonymous hash just so that it can be dereferenced again.

Comment: @DavidO, Like I said, something you want to avoid if at all possible. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a function that "returns a hash". If you have

```
sub foo {
    ...
    return %hash;
}

my %h = foo();
```

then foo doesn't "return a hash"; it returns a *list* of the keys and values in `%hash`. That list gets used to create the new hash `%h`. As Joel has said, if you return a *reference* to a hash, then `keys %$href` is a thing that makes sense, but you can't run `keys` on a list without assigning it to a hash first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it.  From your function, just return a hash reference, then inside your `foreach` block, the key will be stored in the `$_` variable.  Here's an example:

```
sub ReturnsHash {

    return { key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2' };
}

foreach (keys(%{ReturnsHash()})) {
    print 'key:=' . $_ . "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Eric Fossum: What Perl version are you using?  Perl pre-5.14 probably would need you to dereference the hash reference: `foreach ( keys %{ ReturnsHashref() } ) {.....`.

Comment: Good practice even in 5.14+.

Answer (score 1):

Why return the whole bulky `hash` when you can return `hash reference`!

I would always go for returning a `hash reference`.

```
sub return_hash() {
   ## Code 
   return \%hash;
}
```

And receive it as

```
foreach (keys(%{ return_hash() })) {
 ## code
}
```

And one more thing, it is always taken as good coding convention to write all function names starting with a `small case letter` and words separated via `_`.